# Possible to convert an address assignment to function argument via C macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, memory-mapping

I am working on embedded code and attempting to convert a lot of memory-mapped register assignments to get()/set() function calls. I was wondering if it would be possible to maintain the address assignments sprinkled throughout the code, but change the #defines so they take the assignment in as a function argument.

Old Way:

```
#define MOTOR_REG (*(volatile unsigned char *)(0xFEE002));  //a memory-mapped register
MOTOR_REG = value;        //sets value into the memory-mapped register
```

Desired New Way:

```
#define MOTOR_REG( set_motor_reg(value); )

void set_motor_reg(unsigned char)
{
   //logic to set the motor register
}

MOTOR_REG = value;       //value should be passed in to MOTOR_REG macro
```

So, is this scenario possible with C macros? Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What's wrong with the code the way it is?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield - I suspect the OP has to update an existing code base to use different code to set the registry values (probably add some validations first) and wants to do it with minimal intervention.

Comment: @Franci Penov - Correct, I wish to avoid massive Find+Replace operations if simply changing the #define is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C macros won't allow you to do exactly this, as they are just an advanced search & replace done by the preprocessor. You might however pass the value as a macro parameter:

```
#define MOTOR_REG(value) set_motor_reg(value)

void set_motor_reg(unsigned char) { //logic to set the motor register }

MOTOR_REG(value); //value is passed in to MOTOR_REG macro
```

In the above case, using MOTOR_REG is of course unnecessary as you might call set_motor_reg directly. If you are allowed to use C++, you can achieve the wanted behavior that with operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want with macros.  (You could do this in C++ with operator overloading, but that's probably not an option).

Why are you converting everything to functions if you want to continue using things as if they were variables?